# SQL Query to send e-mail based on records number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sql query:

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @tableHTML =
N'<H1>Table name</H1>' +
N'<table border="1">' +
N'<tr><th>Column name1</th><th>Column name2</th>' +
N'<th>Column name3</th><th>Column name4</th></tr>' +
CAST ( ( select td = login_time, '', 
                td = last_batch, '', 
                td = hostname ,'' ,
                td = loginame, ''
    from master.dbo.sysprocesses
    where loginame<>'sa' and program_name=''
    order by last_batch Desc
          FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>' ;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'profile name',
@recipients='e-mail account',
@subject = 'e-mail subject',
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

But I need only send the e-mail if there are records on query.

Can someone help???

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for the existence of data first.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

If Exists(Select 1 from master.dbo.sysprocesses
    where loginame<>'sa' and program_name='')
    Begin

        SET @tableHTML =
        N'<H1>Table name</H1>' +
        N'<table border="1">' +
        N'<tr><th>Column name1</th><th>Column name2</th>' +
        N'<th>Column name3</th><th>Column name4</th></tr>' +
        CAST ( ( select td = login_time, '', 
                        td = last_batch, '', 
                        td = hostname ,'' ,
                        td = loginame, ''
            from master.dbo.sysprocesses
            where loginame<>'sa' and program_name=''
            order by last_batch Desc
                  FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
        N'</table>' ;

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name = 'profile name',
        @recipients='e-mail account',
        @subject = 'e-mail subject',
        @body = @tableHTML,
        @body_format = 'HTML' ;
    End
```

Comment: This query runs perfectly in Query Window but I still have a problem: I use this query in a job and every time I run the job, even "If Exists" return False, the job sends an e-mail (empty)... Any idea??

Comment: The code, as I posted it, should take care of that.  Please double check your code and specifically look for the begin and end statements.  Without a Begin/End, an IF statement only works on the very next "command".  In this case, the command would bet the set statement.

Comment: I know that, but in fact, like I said the query works perfectly when I run in the query editor. So, when I copy/paste to the job, it happens what I said... Always send an e-mail! Probably I have some problem in the job itself... Thank you anyway!

Comment: I found the problem! :) I have made some changes in the where clause and I forgot to put the same changes in the If statement. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad you got your problem resolved.  Please do not be offended by me mentioning the Begin/End stuff.  I don't know what you know.  And you do make a good point about it working in the query window but not in a job.  I should have inferred that you already knew about the Begin/End thing.  For that, I apologize.

Comment: No, no, no! Please, do not apologize. I greatly appreciate your help and did not want to seem offended at all, quite the contrary - just wanted to reinforce the fact that I've already seen this perspective. You gave me a great help as I'm new in these things, as you see, but also to apologize? No please - thank you!!